# I'm getting a compiler error trying to update Java version to 13

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-8

I'm trying to move a Spring-Boot project written in Java 8 to Java 13 but I'm getting the following error during compilation:

> Information:java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (13.0.1).
>   Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting
>   page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database
>   (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the
>   following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler
>   in your report. Thank you.

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Incorrect number of arguments; expected 1, found 0
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:162)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:661)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1737)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitLambda(TransTypes.java:541)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1914)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateArgs(TransTypes.java:213)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:664)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1737)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitBinary(TransTypes.java:743)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:2096)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitParens(TransTypes.java:715)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCParens.accept(JCTree.java:1954)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitIf(TransTypes.java:604)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1492)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1030)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitIf(TransTypes.java:605)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1492)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1030)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitMethodDef(TransTypes.java:490)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:876)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitClassDef(TreeTranslator.java:139)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateClass(TransTypes.java:943)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitClassDef(TransTypes.java:476)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:784)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateTopLevelClass(TransTypes.java:967)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1558)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1437)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:972)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
java.lang.AssertionError: Incorrect number of arguments; expected 1, found 0
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:162)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:661)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1737)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitLambda(TransTypes.java:541)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1914)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateArgs(TransTypes.java:213)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:664)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1737)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitBinary(TransTypes.java:743)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:2096)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitParens(TransTypes.java:715)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCParens.accept(JCTree.java:1954)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitIf(TransTypes.java:604)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1492)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1030)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitIf(TransTypes.java:605)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1492)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1030)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitMethodDef(TransTypes.java:490)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:876)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitClassDef(TreeTranslator.java:139)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateClass(TransTypes.java:943)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitClassDef(TransTypes.java:476)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:784)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:455)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateTopLevelClass(TransTypes.java:967)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1558)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1437)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:972)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

My current JVM is:

```
java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My Maven version is:

```
Maven home: /opt/maven/apache-maven
Java version: 13.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I'm running on IntelliJ 2019.2.

I've also updated Maven build plugin to:

```xml
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>13</source>
          <target>13</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Also the project's JDK configuration and language features on IntelliJ.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Open, yet to be resolved: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225559

Comment: what is the spring boot version?

Comment: Spring-Boot 2.2.2

Comment: Looking @jarmod's comment, I've realized the problem comes from Guava transitive dependence. The only library using Guava on my project is Swagger2. By removing it, I was able to compile.

Comment: Yea ... if you are using a "brand new" release, you can run into edge-case bugs in the compiler.  Stick to the LTS releases if you need stability.

Comment: @StephenC we are running in jdk-13 several pods already. if you stick to `LTS`, the next upgrade is going to be to jdk-17,  wondering how that upgrade will happen to jump 6 releases.

Comment: Notwithstanding that, you won't get stability with the non-LTS releases. For example, you will need to upgrade roughly once every 6 months.  Complete with a new set of features (and a new set of bugs).  That is not stability.

Comment: But in this case, using LTS wouldn't help because the bug apparently is present in Java 11 as well.

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried to run with JDK 11. @StephenC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we ran out of time and we had to face this problem until we get a solution or a workaround. And we finally did it.

In our case what was breaking the compiler was an extra parenthesis accidentally put in (or left there by a inattentive refactorer) a QueryDSL's `BooleanBuilder` expression.

This breaks the compiler (extra parenthesis):

```java
conditionsDue.and((payable.totalInBrl.gt(BigDecimal.ZERO)));
//----------------^--------------------------------------^
```

This compiles successfully (no extra parenthesis):

```java
conditionsDue.and(payable.totalInBrl.gt(BigDecimal.ZERO));
```

I hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch from java 1.8 you need to take into consideration the following:

You have additional dependencies to add, like:

```
javax.annotation-api
jaxb-api
jaxws-api
javax.jws
```

Try to add these JVM arguments:

```
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```